# Parallel Stress Testing using Gatling using message passing between scenarios

Tags: gatling, stress-testing

Considering those pseudo rest APIs:

- User creation: It gives me back a token to use for authentication
- Post creation: It takes the id of the user previously created
- Like: It takes the id of the user and the id of the post
- Comment: It takes the id of the post and the user (plus a message)

It seems to me not very straight forward from a Gatling point of view creating those step in an asynchronous way.
I expect to have something that creates users, let's say 100 and in the meantime something else that was taking all the created user randomly until that moment and create posts. Something else that was waiting to have post to put likes and comments.
Is it possible to do it on fly? I mean without having all the data since the very beginning of the execution or without waiting for the user creation scenario?

My current implementation seems quite odd to me and doesn't really reflect what I had in mind

```kotlin
class MySimulation : Simulation() {

    val createdUsers = ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>()

    val services = http
        .baseUrl("https://services-something.com")
        .doNotTrackHeader("1")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .contentTypeHeader("application/json")
        .acceptHeader("application/json")

    val userTokens = ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>()

    val users = scenario("User Creation")
        .feed(csv("data/users.csv", '"').random())
        .exec(
            createUser()
                .check(
                    status().shouldBe(200),
                    jsonPath("$.result.token.token").saveAs("userToken"),
                    jsonPath("$.result.userInfo.uid").saveAs("userId"),
                )
        )
        .exec { session ->
            // Think about a different approach
            val userToken = session.get<String>("userToken") ?: ""
            val userId = session.get<String>("userId") ?: ""
            userTokens[userId] = userToken
            session
        }
        .pause(1)


    // This is a sort of hand made rotation feeder for users
    private fun availableUsers(userHashMap: ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>) = sequence {
        while (true) {
            yieldAll(userHashMap.map { entry -> mapOf("userId" to entry.key, "userToken" to entry.value) })
        }
    }

    init {
        setUp(
            users.injectOpen(rampUsers(10).during(10))
                .andThen(
                    scenario("Post creation")
                        .feed(availableUsers(userTokens).iterator())
                        .exec(
                            createPostWithHashTag("#{userToken}")
                        )
                        .injectOpen(
                            rampUsers(30).during(40)
                        )
                )
        ).protocols(services)
    }
}
```

This implementation has many problems.

1. It creates users in a sync block before the "Post creation" scenario
2. It can not continue to distribute the user creation through the full execution of the stress test (creating new users and keep posting and liking)

Is it correct to think about those scenarios in parallel using Gatling? Is it a correct approach in gatling to have a sort of message passing between those, like a pub sub feeder?
I guess a blocking feeder (waiting for data from the) is not the correct approach due to the fact it would change the expected user/operations threshold given into initial parameters (like rampUser(10).during(100))

Do you have any example of something parallel that creates users and start to create other resources from those specifying the number of the users and a different number of resources created in parallel?